# Comparison between 2 src in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to compare 2 image src in this code. It's not working, maybe because the paths of these src are not absolute. So how to have the absolute paths of these images?

HTML

```
  <td><img  id='1' src="photo1.gif" onclick="func(this)" ></td>
  <td ><img id='2' src="photo2.gif" onclick="func(this)"></td>
  <td ><img id='3'  src="photo3.gif" onclick="func(this)"></td>
```

JS

```
<script>
 function compare()
if(document.getElementById('1').src==document.getElementById('2').src)
alert("photo1=photo2")
</script>
```

Comment: The code you've provided "doesn't work" for a variety of reasons, not the least of which is a syntax error (which would be visible on your browser's development console, which you should always check).  You've incorrectly defined a function, and you also have no function called `func` which you're trying to call.  The comparison of two values has nothing to do with the problems you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison is fine. The underlying code is not (the func() function is not defined, the compare() function is not well structured, and you should refrain from using just numbers as IDs).

```js
document.getElementById("compareButton").addEventListener("click", function() {

    console.log(document.getElementById('photo1').src+" - "+document.getElementById('photo2').src);
  
    if(document.getElementById('photo1').src == document.getElementById('photo2').src)
    {
     console.log("photo1=photo2");
    }else{
        console.log("different");
    }
});
```

```html
 <table>
 <tr>
   <td><img id="photo1" src="photo1.gif" /></td>
   <td><img id="photo2" src="photo2.gif" /></td>
   <td><img id="photo3" src="photo3.gif" /></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
  
  <button id="compareButton">
    Compare
  </button>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65219491/compare-duplicates-of-images-in-arrays i am having a similar issue if you would be able to check? would greatly appreicate